# angularjs - directive-like component

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

Here is an example in which I show the difference between implementing an **ng-repeat item** as directive or as component.

I have an **ng-repeat** on a list of news.

```
<div ng-repeat="story in $ctrl.news" class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    ...
</div>
```

Since I care about reusability I thought of creating a directive (or component) that displays a story and added the following within the `ng-repeat` div element.

```
<story-thumb story="story"></story-thumb>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1: Implemeting story-thumb as Directive:**

```
app.directive('storyThumb', function(){
  return {
    restrict : 'E',
    scope : {
      story : '='
    },
    templateUrl : 'components/news/story/storythumb.html'
  }
});
```

In story view we can use something like:

```
<h3>{{story.title}}</h3>
```

**Option 2: Implementing story-thumb as Component:**

```
app.component('storyThumb', {
  bindings : {
    story : '<'
  },
  templateUrl : 'components/news/story/storythumb.html'
});
```

In story view we can use something like:

```
<h3>{{$ctrl.story.title}}</h3>
```